# How to add button to call a specific number

Tags: android

I want to add a button to my app that will allow the phone to call a particular number.
I also want to add message service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code for calling particular number

```
call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//here call is the button
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                String Numb = "tel:" + repphone;// repphone is phonr num
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri
                        .parse(Numb));
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Modules.showLongMessage(contact.this, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Add this in the onClick:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

write following code in button.onClickListener,

```
String url = "tel:3334444";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer to this example on making a `Phone Call`.